# Checking if an NSURL is instantiated in Swift vs. Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, nsurl

I'm presently taking an iOS development course. As an assignment, I'm tasked with enabling iCloud on a project. I've found [Tim Roadley's post](http://timroadley.com/2012/04/03/core-data-in-icloud/) to be helpful in explaining the process. The wrinkle: I've built my project in Swift.

In particular, one of the "checks" Mr. Roadley built in to check if there's an instance of the iCloud doesn't translate well to Swift. I'm trying to test if there's an instance of an NSURL called iCloud that's instantiated; if so, do one thing, if not do another.

**From Mr. Roadley's tutorial:**

```
            NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

            if (iCloud) {

                NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

                // a bunch of code

                } else {
                NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

                // a bunch of code

                }
```

So I tried to convert that statement to Swift, as follows:

```
        let iCloud: NSURL = fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil)!

        // TODO: having trouble "swiftifying" this line
        if (iCloud) {
            println("iCloud is working!")
        } else {
            println("iCloud is NOT working!")
        }
```

The compiler says this: `Type 'NSURL' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'`

What obvious thing am I missing?

**Edit:**

Thank you all for such fantastic, fast responses. They are greatly appreciated and I've learned something here.

Comment: `if (iCloud)` - how is that supposed to work, in Swift, for NSURL (which is not magically convertible to a boolean)? [It works in Objective-C due to `if` working over integer types including pointers, but such is not Swift.. use an explicit compare.]

Comment: `if iCloud != nil` to check if it exists

Comment: @user2864740 That's my question. I d/l'ed the code referenced at the top in Obj-C and no compiler errors. How would I check if `iCloud` is instantiated in Swift.

Comment: So there is the question: "How to check if a variable is nil in Swift?" (Once distilling it to this, with a bit of help, it should be easy to find answers - note that is technically the same thing the Objective-C code does :)

Comment: @Bluehound I tried, too and compiler says `Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments` when I type `if (iCloud != nil)`

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer now. I didn't see the explicitly unwrapped NSURL when I commented that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's equal to nil, or you can use the `if let` to unwrap it if it exists. `fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil)` returns an optional NSURL, so you handle that as such:

**Swift 3+**

```
if let cloudURL = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil) {
    print("iCloud is working!")
} else {
    print("iCloud is NOT working!")
}
```

**Older Versions**

```
let iCloud = fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil) // Remove the "!", and this should return an optional

if iCloud != nil {
    println("iCloud is working!")
} else {
    println("iCloud is NOT working!")
}
```

or with `if let`:

```
if let iCloud = fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil) {
    // exists
} else {
    // doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: In otherwords the best habit for explicitness in Objective-C is also the right one in Swift when checking whether or not an object is nil when the object inherits from NSObject

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will crash your application if fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier doesn't succeed.

```
let iCloud: NSURL = fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil)!
```

In Objective-C, this method returns either a URL or nil. In Swift, there are no nil objects. Therefore the method returns an optional URL. By using the ! you force that optional URL to be unwrapped. Unlike Objective-C, you don't get a valid URL or nil, you get a valid URL or a crash.

The variable iCloud is therefore an NSURL*, and it is guaranteed to be not nil (because you would have crashed). There is no point checking whether iCloud is nil or not, because it can't be nil.

If you remove the ! then iCloud becomes an optional NSURL*. In that case, you can check whether it has a value by checking

```
if (iCloud != nil)
```

The syntax

```
if (iCloud)
```

is illegal. An if statement requires a boolean value, and Swift doesn't just convert everything to a boolean value (it was legal at some point, but then people figured out that optional booleans were a nightmare if this was allowed).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the best tool for this is `if-let`:

```
if let iCloud = fileManager.URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier(nil) {
    println("iCloud is working!") // And you can access iCloud here
} else {
    println("iCloud is NOT working!") // And you don't need iCloud here
}
```

Of course, if these are very long, you should likely move them into their own functions, and have the "can access" function take a full `NSURL` rather than an optional one. That way you don't have lots of code nested inside of an `if`. But beyond that, `if-let` is the normal tool for this kind of problem.